# Using a Font via Graphics Environment for Java Graphics returning IOException

Tags: java, fonts, ioexception

All of this code gets called one through the init method which is called in the constructor.

```
private void init() {
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(/"sst.TTF")));
    } catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When run, I face this problem:

```
    java.io.IOException: Can't read \sst.TTF
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.somepackage.Window.Game.init(Game.java:46)
    at com.somepackage.Window.Game.<init>(Game.java:29)
    at com.somepackage.Window.Game.main(Game.java:130)
```

Which doesn't let me use the use the font for my game, [this](http://prntscr.com/58xewm) is how the structure of the files look like in Eclipse:

**What I've tried:**
Using the `InputStream` method, no error was shown, although it didn't work. Hence after some research, I concluded that this was the best method for me to use, although this method isn't working due to an `IOException`, I cannot really use this font because of this `IOException` in my game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this,

Using:

```
private void init() throws FileNotFoundException, FontFormatException, IOException {
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Neil/Desktop/pkmnem.ttf"))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 28);
    this.font = font;
}
```

That was the code, in case if anyone else has this problem in the future.